# Javascript Atom: Array Problems

Tags: javascript, arrays, github, atom-editor

So, for a final project I'm trying to make a game with three different meteors; Bronze, Silver and Gold. While the Bronze array works fine in Setup(), the Silver and Gold meteors go at high speeds for some unknown reason.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  spaceship = new Spaceship(100, 100, 5, spaceshipImage, bulletImage, 40);
  healthStar = new Star(1000, 100, 10, healthStarImage, 50);


//the Meteor Array
// Run a for loop numMeteor times to generate each meteor and put it in the array
// with random values for each star
for (let i = 0; i < numMeteor; i++) {
  let meteorX = random(0, width);
  let meteorY = random(0, height);
  let meteorSpeed = random(2, 20);
  let meteorRadius = random(10, 60);
  meteor.push(new Meteor(meteorX, meteorY, meteorSpeed, meteorBronzeImage, meteorRadius));
  }
}

// draw()
//
// Handles input, movement, eating, and displaying for the system's objects
function draw() {
// Set the background to a safari scene
  background(skyBackground);
// Check if the game is in play
  if (playing == true) {

// Handle input for the tiger
  spaceship.handleInput();

// Move all the "animals"
  spaceship.move();
  healthStar.move();

if (spaceship.dodges >= 5){
  levelTwo = true;
}
  //lvl 2
  if (levelTwo == true){
    meteor = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numMeteor; i++) {
      let meteorX = random(0, width);
      let meteorY = random(0, height);
      let meteorSpeed = random(2, 20);
      let meteorRadius = random(10, 60);
      meteor.push(new Meteor(meteorX, meteorY, meteorSpeed, meteorSilverImage, meteorRadius));
  }
}

if (spaceship.dodges >= 8){
  levelThree = true;
}
//lvl 3
if (levelThree == true){
  levelTwo = false;
  meteor = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < numMeteor; i++) {
      let meteorX = random(0, width);
      let meteorY = random(0, height);
      let meteorSpeed = random(2, 20);
      let meteorRadius = random(10, 60);
      meteor.push(new Meteor(meteorX, meteorY, meteorSpeed, meteorGoldImage, meteorRadius));
    }
}

// Handle the tiger and lion eating any of the star
  spaceship.handleEating(healthStar);

  //
  spaceship.handleBullets();

// Handle the tragic death of the tiger
  spaceship.handleDeath();

// Check to see when the game is over
  checkGameOver();

// Display all the "animals"
  spaceship.display();
  healthStar.display();

// Display and making sure the tiger can eat the copies of the star
for (let i = 0; i < meteor.length; i++) {
meteor[i].move();
meteor[i].display();
//meteor[i].handleDamage();
spaceship.handleHurting(meteor[i]);
spaceship.handleDodging(meteor[i]);

}
 }
   // Once the game is over, display a Game Over Message
 if (gameOver == true) {
    displayGameOver();
  }
    // Otherwise we display the message to start the game
  else {
    displayStartMessage();
      }
    }
```

I've tried to change the speeds, made the levels false, nothing's working other than the Bronze meteors.

Comment: you mention a Setup() function in the question, but it isnt present in the code. Presumably the code you've provided is the body of that function? Making it explicit would be helpful context - we can't see parts of your project that arent provided. Along those lines, whatever code is responsible for meteor movement - where your description suggests the problem may lie - is not included.
Off topic suggestion: the code youre using to fill your meteor array is identical in each case except for the image. Extract it to a function with the image as a parameter. Dont repeat yourself (DRY)

Comment: I just edited it in to include everything, I thought putting too much would be too confusing. My apologies.

Comment: No need to apologize. Ideally you want as much as is required to provide adequate context to someone who has never seen your project.

Comment: (Also known as a [mcve].)

Comment: Not quite sure it's related to your problem, but your level 2 and level 3 meteor initialization is inside your draw loop. They include a `meteor = []`. From what you've provided, that suggests your meteor array is getting cleared every single draw iteration. They never have a chance to move, you're getting fresh random meteors each time.

Comment: @Andy thank you! I had forgotten the proper term/link

Comment: If the array clearing within your draw loop is in fact the issue, you'll need to add a way to track if the level initialization has been completed, so that it only occurs once. A simple flag, an idempotent function, something like that.

Comment: So from what I can understand, I can't have the meteor = [ ] in the draw loop for each level. I have to somehow create them in set up, not in draw? Because I'd preferable like Silver and Gold to move at different speeds as well

Comment: You can call the silver/gold setup in the draw loop, you just have to make sure it is only being called *once*. Right now the code you've provided will execute that `level === ` check each time, and as you aren't clearing the `levelThree` flag, for example, it will be true every time - and recreate your entire meteor array, randomly, each time. Unless there's something you've not included in the post

Comment: So, I removed the meteor = [ ] from all the levels. The meteors move at a normal pace, but now they pop up like crazy in insane numbers

Comment: Let me know if my answer is clearer. Conceptually, you need to separate 'setting up the world state for a given level' from 'updating entity/object states during a level'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your level 2 and level 3 meteor initialization is inside your draw loop. They include a `meteor = []` statement. From what you've provided, that suggests your meteor array is getting cleared every single draw iteration. They never have a chance to move, you're getting fresh random meteors each time.

If the array clearing within your draw loop is in fact the issue, you'll need to add a way to track if the level initialization has been completed, so that it only occurs once. A simple flag, an idempotent function, something like that.

```
// Extract meteor generation to it's own function so you dont need to repeat it
function generateMeteors(meteorImage) {
  let meteor = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numMeteor; i++) {
    let meteorX = random(0, width);
    let meteorY = random(0, height);
    let meteorSpeed = random(2, 20);
    let meteorRadius = random(10, 60);
    meteor.push(new Meteor(meteorX, meteorY, meteorSpeed, meteorBronzeImage, meteorRadius));
  }
  return meteor;
}


function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  spaceship = new Spaceship(100, 100, 5, spaceshipImage, bulletImage, 40);
  healthStar = new Star(1000, 100, 10, healthStarImage, 50);


  //the Meteor Array
  // meteor is apparently global, or otherwise in scope here
  meteor = generateMeteors(meteorBronzeImage)  
}


function draw() {
 /**  
    Code removed for clarity  
 **/

  if (spaceship.dodges >= 5) {
    levelTwo = true;
  }
  //lvl 2
  // levelTwoInitialized tracks if we've initialized the meteor array for this level
  if (levelTwo == true && levelTwoInitialized == false){
    meteor = generateMeteors(meteorSilverImage);
    levelTwoInitialized = true;
  }

  if (spaceship.dodges >= 8){
    levelThree = true;
  }
  //lvl 3
  // levelThreeInitialized tracks if we've initialized the meteor array for this level
  if (levelThree == true && levelThreeInitialized == false){
    levelTwo = false;
    meteor = generateMeteors(meteorGoldImage);
    levelThreeInitialized = true;
  } 

  //... rest of code
```

One possible way to do this is above. Level initialization flags like `levelThreeInitialized` would have to be declared somewhere, wherever you're tracking your game/program state.

If you want to retain the previous level's meteors, you could do something like:

```
  if (levelTwo == true && levelTwoInitialized == false){
    // add silver meteors to the existing bronze set
    meteor = meteor.concat(generateMeteors(meteorSilverImage));
    levelTwoInitialized = true;
  }
  //... rest of code
```

If you want to create a new set with multiple types:

```
  if (levelTwo == true && levelTwoInitialized == false){
    // make NEW silver and bronze meteors
    meteor = generateMeteors(meteorSilverImage)
                .concat(generateMeteors(meteorBronzeImage);
    levelTwoInitialized = true;
  }
  //... rest of code
```

Comment: Would I just have a let levelThreeInitialized = false on the top of the code in the beginning for that to work?

Comment: Something like that. You could put it wherever you initially create the `meteor` variable youre using.